# Python Tkinter - get selection on Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I need to retrieve the value of Radiobutton clicked and then use this value .

What is the way to retrieve the value of a Radiobutton clicked ?

the code to setup the Radiobutton is:

```
radio_uno = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config1', value=1,variable = 1)
radio_uno.pack(anchor=W,side=TOP,padx=3,pady=3)
radio_due = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config2', value=2,variable =1)
radio_due.pack(anchor=W,side=TOP,padx=3,pady=3)
radio_tre = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config3', value=3,variable = 1)
radio_tre.pack(anchor=W,side=TOP,padx=3,pady=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution:
Create a `tk.IntVar()` to track which button was pressed. I'm assuming you did a `from tkinter import *`.

```
radio_var = IntVar()
```

You'll need to change the way you declared your buttons:

```
radio_uno = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config1', value=1,variable = radio_var)
radio_due = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config2', value=2,variable = radio_var)
radio_tre = Radiobutton(Main,text='Config3', value=3,variable = radio_var)
```

Then use the `get()` method to view the value of `radio_var`:

```
which_button_is_selected = radio_var.get()
```

Then you can make an `enum` or just three `if` clauses that'll do stuff depending on which button is chosen:

```
if(which_button_is_selected == 1):
    #button1 code
elif(which_button_is_selected == 2):
    #button2 code
else(which_button_is_selected == 3):
    #button3 code
```

Comment: It's not just _one_ solution, it's the _right_ solution.