# How to get the value of radiobutton in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'd like to get the value as text and not integer on my raddiobutton.
I have a frame, named "printers_frame" in which I created radio buttons with a list of printers on the computer of the user.
According to the printer choosen (radiobutton), I will print files on this specific printer.
I followed [this tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317346/python-tkinter-get-selection-on-radiobutton) but I want to do the same with String, not Integer.

Here is the code to create the radio button:

```
print_variable = StringVar()
for p in printers:
    Radiobutton(printers_frame, text = p[2], variable = print_variable, value = p[2], wraplength=int(WIDTH/3)-10, justify="left", bg=BACKGROUND).pack(side = TOP, anchor = W)
```

Can you help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you just take the integer value, and convert it with ```str()```?

Comment: Do you want to get the text of the Radiobutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just take the integer value, and convert it with `str()`?

You can save that in a variable, and use it however you want.

Hopefully, this helps.

Edit:

Say the value of the RadioButton is `RadioButton()`.

You can just do `str(RadioButton)`.

Edit: You can use the `StrVar()` function in tkinter. You assign your Radio Button to that variable, and then you can use the value as a string.

Then pass the variable with the string when you are initializing your Radio Button. Pass it to a parameter called `variable`.

So, your radio button would be:

```
radio_variable = IntVar()
button = RadioButton(master, ..., variable = radio_variable)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Of course, I can use a dictionary, but I thought there exists a better way to retrieve the value.

Comment: Could you accept this answer, so other people know what the answer to this question is?